# How to branch multiple module maven project in CVS?

Tags: java, maven, branch, cvs, multi-module

I'm having some doubts about the branching method for multi-module projects.
I have my maven project on CVS and I'm intending to create a branch. 
The thing is that I'm not very comfortable with the suggested solution I was given. I'm suposed to branch the whole project instead of the module that I'm modifying.

Is that ok?

I mean, this module in question could be a project itself, but we have it as a module in order to wrap up all the client's projects as modules in one maven project.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show as an example the folder structure of such a project?

Answer (score 0):

You should branch the whole project cause it is simpler and does not produce any problems. Furthermore if you just branch single modules of a multi-module project you will ran into problems to do release of such a thing and loose the synchronization between the modules.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about the same things.  And I even tried to ask this question on the maven users list, but I got little in the way of answers.  Here's what I believe to be the best answer.

First, some realities of the maven build world.

1) Multi-module builds are a nice way to make a group of things build together.  But I think they are a more tight coupling of modules than required by the simple use case of "A should be built before B"  -- this looser coupling is something better handled by Jenkins triggers.

2) Multi-module builds want to be structured as a directory tree, though this isn't necessarily always what you want.  It creates a coupling between source control structure, branching and build logic.

3) Branching is a complicated thing tied to all of points 1 and 2, as well as your software delivery / release model.  It also can be a nightmare for your developers . . .

My suggestsions ( for myself as well as you ):

1) Don't create your build, your source control structure, your branches, or anything . . . with our a set of requirements in hand.  Like other aspects of software engineering, requirements are a must.  They seem to be skipped over in this realm even more easily than in coding.

2) Don't branch nothing you don't actually have to do concurrent development on. If your build structure is forcing you to branch code that isn't actually seeing concurrent development, something is wrong.

3) After you get your requirements, create some possible build, scm, release solutions and walk through them on paper to see how the branching and building plays out.

This could have been a comment, but I actually don't think there is a straightforward "answer"; so this will have to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this for a while myself. I agree with @chad in that there's no straightforward answer, which is very surprising since hundreds of people must be facing this issue.

My experience is in the context of maven+cvs+jenkins, so keep in mind that some of the advantages i'll mention are really advantages in a jenkins context

My take is that you should only branch the submodules that actually have different code (basically chad's #2). More than that, i discovered that the whole branching and building  goes much better if you tweak the canonical maven multi-module structure; specifically, separate the aggregator POM from the parent POM, which normally are together in a single POM. What this will buy you is that now in your build system you can build each submodule + parent POM completely separate and branch them at your will. If you don't separate them, systems like jenkins will create their own submodules which are not branchable.

So basically my structure looks like this

```
root
--pom.xml (aggregator)
--parent
----pom.xml
--subModA
----pom.xml
--subModB
----pom.xml
```

For completeness, my biggest problem with branching the whole structure is that you have parts of several branches that are the same. This ends up creating complexity in your dependencies, where say v1.1 of subModA needs v1.1 of subModB and will fail with subModB v1.0 when in reality 1.0 would be perfectly fine since there were no changes. On the other hand, if you branch but don't increment the version in the modules that didn't change (subModB in my example) you will be deploying multiple snapshots of exactly the same code. This useless deploys might trigger unnecessary actions (think testing, QA for example)